# LINQ Advice - Using ToList().ForEach instead of 'classic' ForEach iteration

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to use LINQ's ForEach construct and am not sure how to convert the following.

My current implementation:

```
var employees = (from e in employeeDepartmentList select e.Employee).ToList();
employeeList = new EmployeeList();
foreach (var emp in employees)
{
   employeeList.Add(emp);
}
```

I am thinking something like this:

```
employeeList = new EmployeeList();
var employees = (from e in employeeDepartmentList select e.Employee).ToList().ForEach(emp => employeeList.Add(emp));
```

Comment: Your snippets do exactly the same thing, yes. Although depending on the implementation requirements of EmployeeList, you could probably make it more performant.

Comment: maybe there's a typo: foreach (var *emp* in employees)

Comment: Alex - they don't; I get design-time error on the second one - it is saying "Cannot assign 'void' to an implicitly-typed local variable."

Comment: vulkanino - yes, you are right, I fixed the typo, thx!

Comment: Ron - as per my question "... how to convert the 'old' implementation using ForEach to using LINQ's ForEach construct... " - I didn't think my question was unclear or ambiguous.

Comment: @user118190: I understand now what was asked--however usually questions end with a `?` and start with something like "How do I.." or "What is the...".  I think you having what is effectively a working answer in your question threw me off.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ForEach` is not a LINQ method, it is a method of `List<>`. In this simple scenario, why even use that? `employeeList.AddRange(employees)` would be even simpler. Even further, if `employees` is already a list, do you need `employeeList`?

As for more advice on using foreach vs. ForEach in general, see: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx

Comment: Thanks Anthony for your reply - employees is already a list, but if you notice, it is getting data from a List of type <EmployeeDepartments>.  I would like to search this list of EmployeeDepartments and basically get the Employee properties out and "cast" it into a List<Employee>.  Am I doing this totally wrong?

Comment: If e.Employee is of type `Employee`, then `employees` will be a `List<Employee>`. I see that `employeeList` is a different type (`EmployeeList()`), so I cannot speak to say that `AddRange` is available to it (it is a member of `List<>`, and I don't know if `EmployeeList` inherits from this or not).

Comment: Thaks Anthony - I just looked at the link you sent me and that solution worked for me.

foreach(Foo foo in foos){ statement involving foo; }
into this code:
foos.ForEach((Foo foo)=>{ statement involving foo; });

Answer (score 1):

Here is the option we decided to go with. We added a class to house extension methods. By placing this in a common assembly, we can use it throughout the enterprise

```
   public static class IEnumerableExtensions
   {
      public static void ForEach<T>( this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action )
      {
         foreach ( T item in source )
            action( item );
      }
   }
```

Comment: What do you get out of using this instead of a foreach loop? This will be slightly less performant, without any benefit. And it's also a little unexpected for a Linq function to not be lazily evaluated. As my colleague said when he saw something like this: "Linq is a query language, not a do-ey language."

Comment: P.S. The intent of the List<T>.ForEach method is performance. It skips the whole .GetEnumerator() and .MoveNext() code. However, you're getting the lousy syntax without the performance benefit here.

Comment: Calling `.ToList().ForEach(...)` loops you data twice so it actually slows your code down.